# Prove that $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$ holds true for $n ≥ 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I've been trying to figure out this proof for way too long now, I'm just not sure where to begin for the inductive step. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: they put up a nice graphical proof on mathfail recently.  http://math-fail.com/2014/07/math-is-beautiful.html

Answer (score 2):

Suppose it holds for some $n \geq 1$.

Claim: It holds for $n+1$, too.

Proof: We have

\begin{align*}
\left(1+ 2 + \ldots + n + (n+1) \right)^2 & = \left(1 + 2 + \ldots + n \right)^2 + 2 \left(1 + 2 + \ldots + n \right) (n+1) + (n+1)^2 \\
& = (1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3) + 2\frac{n(n+1)}{2} (n+1) + (n+1)^2 \\
& = (1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3) + n(n+1) ^2 + (n+1)^2 \\
& = 1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3 + (n+1)^3
\end{align*}

(I have made use of Gauss's addition forumla)

The assertion holds trivially for $n = 1$, it follows from induction that it holds for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Excuse my complete lack of knowledge, but I'm not too sure I understand what you did in the very first line. Specifically " + 2( 1 + 2 + ... + n)(n + 1) + (n + 1)^2 ".

Comment: @Confused Let $A=1+2+\ldots + n$ then the first line just reads $[A + (n+1)]^2 = A^2 + 2A(n+1) + (n+1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
(1+2+\dots+n + (n+1))^2 - (1+2+\dots+n )^2
\\= (n+1)(2\times 1+2\times2+\dots+2\times n + (n+1))
$$

now remember that
$$
1+2+\dots+n = \frac12 n(n+1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(1+\ldots+n+n+1)^2 = (1+\ldots+n)^2+2(n+1)(1+\ldots+n)+(n+1)^2 \\
=(1+\ldots+n)^2 + (n+1)(2(1+\ldots+n)+n+1) \\
=(1+\ldots+n)^2 + (n+1)(2(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})+n+1) \\
=(1+\ldots+n)^2 + (n+1)(n+1)(n+1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

To make this proof easier to follow, let's define the following:  $$\begin{align*} A_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n k, \\ B_n &= A_n^2 = \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n k\biggr)^2, \\ C_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n k^3. \end{align*}$$  Then the claim to be proven is that $B_n = C_n$ for all positive integers $n$.  Here, we focus on the inductive step:  that is, we wish to establish that if there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $B_n = C_n$, this implies that $B_{n+1} = C_{n+1}$.  To this end, we first observe $A_{n+1} = (n+1) + A_n$:  hence $$\begin{align*} B_{n+1} &= A_{n+1}^2 = ((n+1) + A_n)^2 \\ &= (n+1)((n+1) + 2A_n) + A_n^2 \\ &= (n+1)(A_n + (n+1) + A_n) + B_n \\ &= (n+1)(A_{n+1} + A_n) + C_n. \end{align*}$$  But note $$A_{n+1} + A_n = (n+1) + \sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=n}^1 ((n+1)-k) = (n+1) + \sum_{k=1}^n (n+1) = (n+1)^2,$$ thus $$B_{n+1} = (n+1)^3 + C_n = C_{n+1},$$ which completes the inductive step.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We know that $\sum_{k=1}^nk={n(n+1)\over 2}$.